# Searching for days where particular subset of records are missing, and if one of the subset is posted out of its supposed timeframe

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies for the terrible title, but it's hard to work out how to describe what I'm after.

I have a table called [Orders], and a table called [Customers] (Customers isn't needed for this question)

| Timestamp | Type | Details | CustID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-10T20:30:34 | S | Blah blah blah | abc123 |
| 2023-03-10T17:35:19 | E | Blah blah blah | abc123 |
| 2023-03-10T13:19:55 | L | Blah blah blah | abc123 |
| 2023-03-10T20:12:05 | B | Blah blah blah | abc123 |
| 2023-03-09T21:23:34 | S | Blah blah blah | cde234 |
| 2023-03-09T16:59:10 | E | Blah blah blah | cde234 |
| 2023-03-09T07:44:03 | B | Blah blah blah | cde234 |
| 2023-03-08T21:09:16 | S | Blah blah blah | efg345 |
| 2023-03-08T18:02:59 | E | Blah blah blah | efg345 |
| 2023-03-08T16:33:47 | L | Blah blah blah | efg345 |
| 2023-03-08T08:19:22 | B | Blah blah blah | efg345 |

The rules these transactions should follow are:

- Each day there should be four main entries, of type B, L, E and S;
- 'B' should be recorded 7am - 9am, 'L' between 11.30am - 2pm, 'E' between 4.30 - 6pm, and 'S' between 7.30pm - 10pm.

Using this data, user cde234 did not log an 'L' transaction at all on 2023-03-09, and user efg345 posted an 'L' transaction 2.5hrs later than the cutoff.

I need to be able to write a query that searches for:

- if B, L, E or S transactions are recorded outside their respective timeframes;
- if there is a B, L, E or S MISSING from any given day.

I have tried writing this myself, but the best I can do is to is the second of these results, through the following code:

```
select c.CustID, sub.timestamp
from [Customers] c
left join
(
    select custID, 
           left(o.timestamp,10) as "TimeStamp",
           count(o.type) as "Count"
    from [Orders] o
    where o.type in ('B', 'L', 'E', 'S')
    group by custID, left(o.timestamp,10)
) sub
where sub.Count < 4
```

I'm aware this is probably terrible code for many reasons, but am looking for proof of concept more than anything else. I'm still learning SQL in my spare time.

Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```sql
select CustID, COUNT(*), COUNT(v.type), CAST(timestamp AS DATE)
from (
    VALUES  (N'2023-03-10T20:30:34', N'S', N'Blah blah blah', N'abc123')
    ,   (N'2023-03-10T17:35:19', N'E', N'Blah blah blah', N'abc123')
    ,   (N'2023-03-10T13:19:55', N'L', N'Blah blah blah', N'abc123')
    ,   (N'2023-03-10T08:12:05', N'B', N'Blah blah blah', N'abc123')
    ,   (N'2023-03-09T21:23:34', N'S', N'Blah blah blah', N'cde234')
    ,   (N'2023-03-09T16:59:10', N'E', N'Blah blah blah', N'cde234')
    ,   (N'2023-03-09T07:44:03', N'B', N'Blah blah blah', N'cde234')
    ,   (N'2023-03-08T21:09:16', N'S', N'Blah blah blah', N'efg345')
    ,   (N'2023-03-08T18:02:59', N'E', N'Blah blah blah', N'efg345')
    ,   (N'2023-03-08T16:33:47', N'L', N'Blah blah blah', N'efg345')
    ,   (N'2023-03-08T08:19:22', N'B', N'Blah blah blah', N'efg345')
) t (Timestamp,Type,Details,CustID)
left join (
    VALUES  ('B', CAST('07:00' AS TIME), CAST('9:00' AS TIME))
    ,   ('L', CAST('11:30' AS TIME), CAST('14:00' AS TIME))
    ,   ('E', CAST('16:30' AS TIME), CAST('18:00' AS TIME))
    ,   ('S', CAST('19:30' AS TIME), CAST('22:00' AS TIME))
    ) v(type, fromTime, toTime)
    ON  v.type = t.type
    AND CAST(timestamp AS TIME) BETWEEN v.fromTime AND v.ToTime
where   t.Type IN ('S','E', 'L', 'B')
group by custID, CAST(timestamp AS DATE)
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT t.type) < 4 -- Not 4 trans at all
OR  COUNT(v.type) <> 4
```

I'm only using order table, but you can join it against customers's dito to fish out customers without orders altogether.

I create a values table which contains the ruleset for your transactions, then i join it, and check count of matching rows. Just to be sure, i only select the types you wanna check (S,E,L,B).

Btw, your data was a bit wrong, i changed '2023-03-10T08:12:05', N'B' transaction for abcd123 customer. Also, probably you need to add OrderID to GROUP BY, but you didn't have it in the sample, so i didn't add it.

EDIT, another version which actually displays what's wrong:

```sql
;WITH data AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (N'2023-03-10T20:30:34', N'S', N'Blah blah blah', N'abc123')
        ,   (N'2023-03-10T17:35:19', N'E', N'Blah blah blah', N'abc123')
        ,   (N'2023-03-10T13:19:55', N'L', N'Blah blah blah', N'abc123')
        ,   (N'2023-03-10T08:12:05', N'B', N'Blah blah blah', N'abc123')
        ,   (N'2023-03-09T21:23:34', N'S', N'Blah blah blah', N'cde234')
        ,   (N'2023-03-09T16:59:10', N'E', N'Blah blah blah', N'cde234')
        ,   (N'2023-03-09T07:44:03', N'B', N'Blah blah blah', N'cde234')
        ,   (N'2023-03-08T21:09:16', N'S', N'Blah blah blah', N'efg345')
        ,   (N'2023-03-08T18:02:59', N'E', N'Blah blah blah', N'efg345')
        ,   (N'2023-03-08T16:33:47', N'L', N'Blah blah blah', N'efg345')
        ,   (N'2023-03-08T08:19:22', N'B', N'Blah blah blah', N'efg345')
    ) t (Timestamp,Type,Details,CustID)
)
, types AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
        VALUES  ('B', CAST('07:00' AS TIME), CAST('9:00' AS TIME))
        ,   ('L', CAST('11:30' AS TIME), CAST('14:00' AS TIME))
        ,   ('E', CAST('16:30' AS TIME), CAST('18:00' AS TIME))
        ,   ('S', CAST('19:30' AS TIME), CAST('22:00' AS TIME))
    ) v(type, fromTime, toTime)
    )
SELECT  grp.*, t.*, CASE WHEN d.CustID IS NULL THEN 'Type missing' ELSE 'Timestamp not in bounds' END AS error
FROM
(
    SELECT  custId, CAST(timestamp AS DATE) AS dt
    FROM    data
    WHERE   Type IN ('S', 'E', 'L', 'B')
    GROUP BY CustID, CAST(timestamp AS DATE)
    )
  grp
CROSS JOIN types t
LEFT JOIN data d
    ON  d.custId = grp.custId
    AND CAST(d.Timestamp AS DATE) = grp.dt
    AND d.Type = t.type
WHERE   d.CustID IS NULL OR d.timestamp NOT BETWEEN t.fromTime AND t.toTime
```

Since it's a bit more complex to conjure rows from thin air, i'm doing it a bit differently.

What i do is create an expected result by doing distinct customer per date cross joined with all the types it should have. This result is left join:ed against the actual data result, and then a case when checks if data doesn't exist at all, or if it falls outside of the bounds. It would be possible to do this in original way, but it gets a bit messy after a while. This version is also a bit less performant since we do a double join.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It gives me almost what I need, and certainly more than I was getting myself. So this shows a list of the number of B,L,E,S orders in the day, and also the number of times those orders weren't placed within the timeframes specified. My only further request would be how to make it show which of them are missing, and which ones were outside of the timeframe?

Comment: Added another version that might be of interest